# Entity Framework Joining Tables With Ranged Foreign Key Relationships

Tags: entity-framework

I'm not sure if "Ranged Foreign Key Relationship" is an actual term or if I just made it up, but this is what I am talking about:

AgeGroup Table

```
int MinAge { get; set; }
int MaxAge { get; set; }
string Description { get; set; }
```

Customer Table

```
public int CustomerID { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }`
public int Age { get; set; }
public virtual AgeGroup AgeGroup { get; set; }
```

Given the above two tables, how can I join them using the (EntityFramework, DataAnnontations, DbContext) and be able to access `Customer.AgeGroup.Description`?

Consider the following example data:

AgeGroup

```
MinAge MaxAge Description
0      12     Youngin
13     19     Teenager
20     29     Twenties
30     39     Thirties
40     9999   Old
```

Customer

```
CustomerID Name        Age
345        Joe Smith   17
493        Cobaltikus  31
631        Jane Doe    29
```

How can I relate these? Cobaltikus has an Age of 31. There is no corresponding AgeGroup record with 31. The corresponding AgeGroup record is the one with MinAge = 30 and MaxAge = 39. I can do this easily in SQL, but how do you do it with EntityFramework?

```
SELECT
  AgeGroup.Description

FROM
  Customer,
  AgeGroup

WHERE
  Customer.CustomerID = 493
  AND AgeGroup.MinAge <= Customer.Age
  AND AgeGroup.MaxAge >= Customer.Age
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AgeGroup` table should not be connected to the `Customer` table by way of a foreign key or Entity Framework construct.

The `AgeGroup` table is in fact a lookup table, but the lookup should occur at **runtime**, not compile time.

You should add some custom code to your model by way of a partial class; and encapsulate this lookup inside of either a property or a 'Get' method.

Here's some example code:

```
using System.Linq;

namespace CobaltikusProject.Models
{
    public partial class Customer
    {
        public string AgeGroup
        {
            get { return EFEntities.AgeGroups.Single(a => a.MinAge <= this.Age && this.Age <= a.MaxAge); }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a "ranged foreign key relationship".  This is not something that relational databases handle (at least not with *foreign keys*).

The way to handle the link between customer and their age group is with a sub-query or a lookup query.  There is no way to do this with a navigation property in EF.  You could create a method on the data context based on a stored procedure that looks up the appropriate age group given a customer key.  This would be almost as easy to use in your code as a navigation property.

Comment: -1: For `stored procedure`. Definitely overkill for this problem.

Comment: @JimG. unless you're shop has policies that restrict all application access to stored procedures, in which case they aren't overkill, they're the mandate.  I see from  your answer that you agree with me that a subquery/lookup method is what is needed.  Thanks for being disagreable though.